# How the installer can find my preseed.cfg file?

Tags: 12.04, preseed

Am following the Ubuntu help(Automating the installation using preseeding) and created the `preseed.cfg` file.

Am trying to install "Ubuntu 12.04 LTS" using USB so kept the preseed.cfg file in top level directory of the pen drive.

When I start trying with bootable USB, I have given `preseed/file=/hd-media/preseed.cfg` as a bootable parameter by pressing <kbd>E</kbd> after highlight the kernel but Manual installation is only happening.

I believe Installer is not finding my `preseed.cfg` file. Can you please guide me that How the installer can find my `preseed.cfg` file?

Regards

Senthil

Answer (score 0):

Currently, Ubuntu just support a subset of Aliases (https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/installation-guide/i386/preseed-using.html)

You don't need:

```
preseed/file=/hd-media/preseed.cfg
```

You should try:

```
file=/hd-media/preseed.seed
```

Please consider to rename your preseed to .seed !